# How can I list movie names by results.title in the UI <li>

Tags: javascript, api, view

I know to show data on repeat in AngularJS , but now I am trying on native javascript.

I have  called data from **TMDB API**. Now I need to list those in UI list.

```js
    function afterLoad() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(data);
    name.src = data.title;
    }

function afterClick() {
    // changed target to focus search
    var terms = document.getElementById("search").value.split(' ').join('+');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener('load', afterLoad);
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=8318c431b4fc8a2c4762bf2a52c351ee&query='+terms);
    request.send();

    }

button.addEventListener("click", afterClick);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <title>Get Movies</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb-3">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 id="header-title">Get Movies<span style="display:none">123</span></h1>
  <input style="align:right" type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="search">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit" id="button">
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="main" class="card card-body">
    <h2 class="title">Add Fav Movies</h2>
    <form class="form-inline mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <h2 class="title">Lists</h2>
    <ul id="items" class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 1</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

- How can I list movie names by `results.title` in the UI `<li class="list-group-item">Item 1</li>` ?
- Also I need to select particular movie by `id` and store in another json collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your afterload function, get the results from data and loop over the items. add `li` to `ul` using `.append`

use [document.createElement](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp) to create a new `li`.

use [document.createTextNode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp) to create text for the newly created `li`.

and [.appendChild()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) to append `li` to `ul`.

```js
function addListItem(title, listId) {
  var ul = document.getElementById(listId);
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.className = 'list-group-item';
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function afterLoad() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var name = document.createElement('img');
    
    const results = data.results;
     
    // loop through items
    results.forEach(item => {
      addListItem(item.title, "items");
    });
    
    name.src = data.title;
    document.body.appendChild(name);
    }

function afterClick() {
    // changed target to focus search
    var terms = document.getElementById("search").value.split(' ').join('+');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener('load', afterLoad);
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=8318c431b4fc8a2c4762bf2a52c351ee&query='+terms);
    request.send();

    }

button.addEventListener("click", afterClick);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <title>Get Movies</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb-3">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 id="header-title">Get Movies<span style="display:none">123</span></h1>
  <input style="align:right" type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="search">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit" id="button">
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="main" class="card card-body">
    <h2 class="title">Add Fav Movies</h2>
    <form class="form-inline mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <h2 class="title">Lists</h2>
    <ul id="items" class="list-group">
      
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have updated my javascript code. I do not want to include `<li>` internally from javascript. Can't I loop it from the HTML ?

Comment: you want to add images inside `<li>`?

Comment: and also please update your question. *How can I list movie names by results.title in the UI <li class="list-group-item">Item 1</li> ?*

Comment: No I don't want images inside `<li>` . I want to pass entire object but only to display it by name.

Comment: @NoobCoder please create a visual example of how you want the data to be.

Comment: Its working fine thanks. I have also mention another problem . Please see my question.

Comment: for that you'll need to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

In your afterload function, get the results from data and loop over the items. add li to ul using .append it the options.

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
var option;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
{
 option += '<div class="list" id="' + data[i].id + '">'+ data[i].Title +'</div>';   
}
$('#items').append(option);
```